# Go time.Ticker fires unpredictably on Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu, go, time, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have a very weird problem.
My ticker fires on my Ubuntu Server way more often than on my laptop.
The code I am using:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        for m := range time.NewTicker(3 * time.Second).C {
            fmt.Printf("miner tick, %s\n", m.String())
        }
    }()
    mutex := sync.Mutex{}
    mutex.Lock()
    mutex.Lock() // so main does not exit 
}
```

This is the output from my laptop, where the ticker behaves just fine:

```
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:10.501114311 +0100 CET m=+3.000369091
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:13.501091057 +0100 CET m=+6.000345958
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:16.501129717 +0100 CET m=+9.000384497
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:19.501132742 +0100 CET m=+12.000387556
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:22.501124748 +0100 CET m=+15.000379558
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:25.501129955 +0100 CET m=+18.000384763
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:28.501074390 +0100 CET m=+21.000329347
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:31.501104596 +0100 CET m=+24.000359376
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:34.501126679 +0100 CET m=+27.000381460
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:37.501136231 +0100 CET m=+30.000391041
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:40.501064832 +0100 CET m=+33.000319616
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:43.501131945 +0100 CET m=+36.000386725
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:07:46.501099862 +0100 CET m=+39.000354648
```

This is the output from my Ubuntu Server:

```
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:21.083678481 +0100 CET m=+3.000187501 // A
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:09.15319572 +0100 CET m=+6.000375001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:12.15338322 +0100 CET m=+9.000562501
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:15.15357072 +0100 CET m=+12.000750001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:18.15375822 +0100 CET m=+15.000937501
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:21.15394572 +0100 CET m=+18.001125001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:24.15413322 +0100 CET m=+21.001312501
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:27.15432072 +0100 CET m=+24.001500001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:30.15450822 +0100 CET m=+27.001687501 // B
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:33.15469572 +0100 CET m=+30.001875001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:36.15888347 +0100 CET m=+33.006062751
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:39.15507072 +0100 CET m=+36.002250001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:24.536503357 +0100 CET m=+39.002437501 // C
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:27.536690857 +0100 CET m=+42.002625001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:30.536878357 +0100 CET m=+45.002812501
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:33.537065857 +0100 CET m=+48.003000001
miner tick, 2018-02-02 11:02:36.541253607 +0100 CET m=+51.007187751
```

Notice the first tick A 
The ticks from B are printed way more rapidly than the ticks before (so definitely not within an interval of 3 seconds)
Notice the ticks from C on. All these ticks also are printed almost instantly after each other

I checked the system time on my Ubuntu server with `hwclock`, but that is fine and always exactly the same as on my laptop.

EDIT:
output of `timedatectl` on my server:

```
    Local time: Fri 2018-02-02 11:30:50 CET
  Universal time: Fri 2018-02-02 10:30:50 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2018-02-02 10:30:50
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

EDIT2:
simplifying the example to:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for {
        fmt.Println(time.Now().String())
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

output on the server:

```
2018-02-02 11:34:48.041731255 +0100 CET m=+0.000000001
2018-02-02 11:34:49.041793755 +0100 CET m=+1.000062501
2018-02-02 11:34:50.041856255 +0100 CET m=+2.000125001
2018-02-02 11:34:51.041918755 +0100 CET m=+3.000187501
2018-02-02 11:34:52.041981255 +0100 CET m=+4.000250001
2018-02-02 11:34:53.042043755 +0100 CET m=+5.000312501
2018-02-02 11:34:54.042106255 +0100 CET m=+6.000375001
2018-02-02 11:34:55.042168755 +0100 CET m=+7.000437501
2018-02-02 11:34:36.234756165 +0100 CET m=+8.000500001
2018-02-02 11:34:37.234818665 +0100 CET m=+9.000562501
2018-02-02 11:34:38.234881165 +0100 CET m=+10.000625001
2018-02-02 11:34:39.234943665 +0100 CET m=+11.000687501
2018-02-02 11:34:40.235006165 +0100 CET m=+12.000750001
2018-02-02 11:34:41.235068665 +0100 CET m=+13.000812501
2018-02-02 11:34:42.235131165 +0100 CET m=+14.000875001
2018-02-02 11:34:43.235193665 +0100 CET m=+15.000937501
2018-02-02 11:34:44.235256165 +0100 CET m=+16.001000001
2018-02-02 11:34:45.235318665 +0100 CET m=+17.001062501
```

Comment: Where is this Ubuntu server? Is it a VM somewhere? Does it have clock synchronization running? (run `timedatectl`). Cloud VMs for example have notoriously crappy clocks, but even that is really pushing it if it's not being rescheduled.

Comment: should have added that, sorry. No, the ubuntu server is right beside me :) real physical system, no vm whatsoever. I edited my question and included the output of timedatectl

Comment: Good to know. Can you try just printing `time.Now()` in a loop with a small sleep in it (1s should do it)? (just simplifying). `timedatectl` would still be helpful too.

Comment: I did that, please see my second EDIT! Same problem, so it is not ticker related

Comment: Thanks. I suspect it's not a Go issue. Can you try `while /bin/true; do date; sleep 1; done` in your shell? You may want to look at logs too, a 20s jump  is usually mentioned.

Comment: yes, not go related at all!  
I did it, and it printed the statements way too fast and jumped 20s back again xD. Which logs would you suggest to look at?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like either a runaway process changing the time, or more likely a bad RTC. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108283/what-could-cause-the-clock-to-jump-by-5-minutes for details on how you can diagnose further. On the Go side, there's a [proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/12914-monotonic.md) to introduce monotonic time, but I don't think that's quite there yet.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for all the help! I could now verify, that the RTC on my Ubuntu server is actually correct, but the system time is not! It runs faster than the RTC and occasionally it resyncs with RTC (round about after 20s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my problem is.
I disabled ACPI on my Ubuntu server in order to detect all 6 gpus I am using. With ACPI on, I can only see 4 of 6 gpus (thats an issue for another question)
With ACPI turned off, somehow my system time is no longer NTP synchronized and runs then slightly faster than my RTC, completely destroying all time dependent applications...

So, no go issue after all (who would have thought that anyway, right? :) )